# MS Word Legacy check box selection to auto populate a field

Tags: forms, checkbox, ms-word, office365

I have used the following code, to autopopulate text into a word document when an option is selected from a drop down box:

```
{ IF {REF DDRH \* MERGEFORMAT }="Yes" "Right Hand Machine Required"
```

I am trying to replicate the process with a legacy check box, however I cannot get the text to auto populate.

```
{ IF { FORMCHECKBOX INFEEDF \* MERGEFORMAT } = "1" "INFEED FRONT" "" }
```

I have checked the bookmark names and they are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, the FORMCHECKBOX result value cannot be tested using field codes - as a workaround you can do it in a VBA "exit macro", or if you can't use VBA for whatever reason you can use a dropdown with (say) "N" and "Y" options instead.